# Scrollable UITableView as an overlay

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, mapkit

I'm trying to replicate the following GIF from Postmates checkout - a scrollable UITableView positioned on top of a MapView. This tableview can be scrolled, with the normal bounce effect if I go too far down or up.

[image]

Currently, I have the MapView and UITableView added as sibling views to my ViewController's view. I have adjusted the frame of the table view to move it down.

```
    CGRect rect =  CGRectMake(
                          0.f,
                          200.f,
                          self.view.bounds.size.width,
                          self.view.bounds.size.height - self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height - 200.f
                          );
```

[image]

The two main issue's I'm having are:

1. I cannot figure out how to drag the entire tableview down when pulling down. E.g. the grey (my `tableView.backgroundColor`) sticks when I scroll down. If however, I make that background clear, then when I drag up, you see the map emerging from behind the view.
2. My cells keep disappearing when I scroll up. I have `clipsToBounds = false`, and I'm not actually dequeuing cells, just creating them in my `cellForRow` method, but they still disappear.

I feel like this should be a straightforward layout, but I'm missing something!

I've tried adjusting the `contentInset` of the table view, but then the scrollbar does not align with the cells as it does in the gif and does not look nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simpler than I thought, no autolayout or crazy weird tricks required.

1. Add a full screen table view to your controller, and insert a full screen map view behind it.

   ```
   self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
   [self.view insertSubview:self.mapView belowSubview:self.tableView];
   ```
2. Add a dummy view with the background color of your table view with a height of around 200 pixels, and a full width, into the `tableFooterView` on your table view.

   ```
   CGFloat footerHeight = 200.0;
   UIView *dummyView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, footerHeight)];
   dummyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
   self.tableView.tableFooterView = dummyView;
   ```
3. Set the content offset of the table view to be the inverse of that footer view's height:

   ```
   CGFloat footerHeight = dummyFooterView.bounds.height;
   self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -footerHeight);
   ```
4. Set the content inset of your table view to offset the footer view.

   ```
   self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(footerHeight, 0, -footerHeight, 0)
   ```
5. Adjust the scrollbar position, again, based on the footer's height.

   ```
   self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(footerHeight, 0, 0, 0);
   ```

This will push down the tableview, ensure the scroll bars match the table view, but allow it to bounce 'up' above its initial position and will ensure the background does not peek through the bottom of the tableview.

Comment: Does your mapView receives any touch events?

Answer (score 0):

We needed similar effect in our app, along with parallax in the underlying view(map here/ we had a photos gallery).

I assume you want something like shown on this blogs video [here](https://medium.com/@dineshk1389/parallax-effects-on-ios-9bd9c794e475)

I wrote a small blog on how to achieve this. You can find this [here](https://medium.com/@dineshk1389/pull-down-table-views-e33d4c85018b)

Basically its just a play of `contentInsets` and `contentOffset` properties of `UITableView`

---

If this does not suits you, here my suggestion in your two main points.

Controller's View has subviews

1. Map View (fills complete super view)
2. UITableView (fills complete super view) and in code set content **insets.top = kHeightOfVisibleMap**